# The system cannot find the file specified. But it is there

Tags: cmd.exe

The following command:

```
copy "%homepath%\Hacking\Coding\Windows\Scripts\Registry\Explorer\Blank.ico" "%SystemRoot%\system32"
```

Returns:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

The file is hidden but there and can be seen by explorer and cmd.
I've tried with and without the double-quotes.
I've tried without using environmental variables.
I've tired making `Blank.ico` unhidden.

I am totally stumped. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ugg! Solved it. Somehow the file became flagged read only. Goodbye half an hour of my life. Maybe this will help someone else mid brain fart.

Comment: Read-only doesn't prevent a file being copied.